# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to1^+}\left({\zeta(n)-\frac{1}{n-1}}\right)$

Tags: limits, riemann-zeta

Let
$$x=\lim_{n\to1^+}\left({\zeta(n)-\dfrac{1}{n-1}}\right)$$
where $\zeta$ is Riemann zeta function. What is the value of $x$?

At $n\to1^+$, $\zeta(n)\to\infty$ and $\dfrac{1}{n-1}\to\infty$, so this is indeterminate form of type $\infty-\infty$. I wrote this limit as
$$x=\lim_{n\to1^+}\dfrac{\zeta(n)^2-\left({\dfrac{1}{n-1}}\right)^2}{\zeta(n)+\dfrac{1}{n-1}}$$
Then I tried to apply L'Hopital's rule, but this limit become more complicated. Also, derivative of zeta function is very complicated, so L'Hopital's rule cannot help evaluating this limit. What is the easiest way to solve it?

Comment: FYI: The limit is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma \approx 0.577 \dots$

Comment: I know the value of limit, but I need to prove it.

Comment: See Equation $25$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)

Comment: For real number $x>0$ and $s\neq 1$ such that $\Re{(s)}>0$ we have $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{1}{n^s} + \frac{x^{1-s}}{s-1}+\frac{\{x\}}{x^s}-s\int_x^{\infty}\frac{\{u\}}{u^{s+1}}\,du.$$ From that you can (for $x=1$) find that $$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{u\}}{u^{s+1}}\,du,$$ so zeta has pole in $s=1$ and...That might help.

Comment: I can prove it using Hermite's formula for Hurwitz zeta function should I post my solution?